# Periodic curve on unit sphere and torsion

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning

Define $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ be the unit sphere. Suppose that $\alpha :\mathbb{R} \to S^2$ is a differentiable curve parametrized by arc-length.

a) Show that $\kappa(s)$, the curvature of $\alpha$ is non-vanishing.

b) Suppose also that  $\alpha$ is $l$-periodic for some $l \in \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha (s+l)=\alpha(s)$). Let $\tau(s)$ be the torsion of $\alpha$. Prove that $$\int_0^l \, \tau(s)\, ds=0.$$

Part a is easy to prove by using the fact that the curve is unit speed. However, I don't know how to solve part b.

Comment: The proof is [there](http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=iybXuGvce8wC&pg=PA231&dq=%22total+torsion%22+of+a+spherical+curve&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wKkzVMCxMpD3at61gagM&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22total%20torsion%22%20of%20a%20spherical%20curve&f=false) p.231 problem 3114